# Counting $K_4$ on two graphs sharing the same vertices

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

> Let $f(G)$ denote the number of $K_4$ in a graph $G$ and $e(G)$ denote the number of edges of $G$.
>
> Consider two simple graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ having the same set $V$ of $n$ vertices and let  $H_1(U)$ and $H_2(U)$ be subgraphs of $G_1$ and $G_2$, respectively, having the same set $U$ of vertices.
>
> If $M= {\max } |e(H_{1}(U))-e(H_{2}(U))|$, over all ${U \subseteq V, H_1 \subseteq G_1, H_2 \subseteq G_2}$, is it true that:
>
> $|f(G_{1})-f(G_{2})| \leq Mn^2$?

I am looking for a proof or reference for the previous problem. Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the subgraphs in your definition **induced**?

Comment: @Moritz Yes, the subgraphs are induced.

Comment: If I'm reading the definitions correctly then $G_1$ and $G_2$ differ in at most $M$ edges.  Each edge is contained in less that $n^2/2$ $K_4$'s, so the inequality is immediate.

Comment: @BenBarber Thank you! It was simpler than I thought.

Comment: @BenBarber Can you repost your comment as an answer so that the question can be closed?